# subsetting rows in R for two max values

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to find the rows for the two states with the highest execution rate. I was able to find the first one (Texas row), with the following command:

```
maxstate = subset(mrate, exec == max(mrate$exec))
```

So I have the first, but need to figure out how to return the rows with the top two values for exec. `mrate` is the dataset.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `order` based on the 'exec' and get the first two or last two rows

```
head(mrate[order(-mrate$exec),], 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

with base `R` you could do something like:

```
mrate[order(-mreate$exec), ][1:2, ]
```

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.